# Errors when backing up Windows server to NAS

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, server-message-block, synology, windows-server-backup

I'm trying to backup several Windows servers to a Synology NAS using the 'Active Backup for Server' package available on the Synology Package Center. The specifics of the package probably aren't too important, as all it's doing is scheduling backups over SMB using stored account credentials. While most of the files are successfully backed up, several files fail to backup and one of two errors is shown for each:

```
"You do not have permission to access the file on the server."
```

or

```
"The file cannot be backed up because it has been opened on the remote server."
```

I have the backups scheduled to run using an Active Directory service account. I've tried assigning membership to the administrators and backup operators groups to the account to resolve the permissions issues, but neither was sufficient to backup all files. Particularly, permissions errors appear when trying to backup the public user profile and administrator profile.

Additional general problem areas for the backup are:

- Windows/WID
- Windows/Temp
- Windows/System32
- Users/MSSQL$MICRSOFT##WID
- Users/.NET v4.5
- ProgramData

I appreciate any attention anyone can give to this issue. Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide that would be helpful.

Also before it is suggested - I can't use Windows Server Backup. Though I agree it would be an elegant solution, backup account credentials cannot be stored locally on these servers per security guidelines, thus I'm using this Synology package.

Comment: IMO, I'd use Windows Server Backup on each server to back up to a share on the NAS rather than trying to use the NAS backup utility.

Comment: @joeqwerty Please read the entire post. I explained why this isn't an option.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. My bad. Sorry.